# Can't access blockchain.info from java due to missing certificate

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to access https://blockchain.info/lastblock from java, 
but the code throws:
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

This is usually due to self signed certificate, but this one is not self signed(you can check it in your browser). Looks like java doesn't user system CA certificates.
Isn't it a bug? 
I exported the certificate and insert it dynamically into java KeyStore, but I don't like this solution(Not sure it will check revocation lists for this certificate etc). 
So what's the best solution to fix the problem?

I used this code to test http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs56/examples/ldap/SimpleQuery/InstallCert.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of roots of trust changes from time to time, and Java's built-in one is often a little different to that of browsers. Those trust roots are what is stored in the system keystore (well, technically in the system truststore) and you can add to them by placing the extra roots that you want to support in a per-user keystore, stored in your home directory. It's in the default location manipulated with `keytool`.

The certificate that you'd *actually* consider putting there — if it isn't already — would be the “COMODO Certification Authority” one; browsers like it (i.e., you *can* verify it independently of Java) but your Java doesn't. It has revokation information signed directly into it, so it should be all you need; SSL/PKI is *supposed* to be able to be bootstrapped from just the root CA certificates.

Comment: Before you ask, I've got no idea at all why your version of Java doesn't support that root CA by default. Are you patched up to date? The CA list is one of the things that changes most often.

Comment: Yeah. Tried both 1.7_51 and 1.8_b126 the same issue. COMODO certificate is not in the list of java certificates. I thought it should use OSX default  Keychain(seems like it loads Apple's java.security.Provider), but...